# How to get latest java package name/version for Chef recipe?

Tags: package, chef-infra

I want to collect latest java versions available in the yum channel. So then I can inform customers if they are happy to do the upgrade. In this case, they will be aware what version will be in place using Chef package upgrade functionality before any change.

Solution:
You can get this using Ohai plugin by executing similar command to this and storing as attribute:

```
root@servername DEV # yum list all jre1.*[5,6,7,8,9].* | tail -n 1
jre1.8.0_72.x86_64        1.8.0_72-fcs         repositoryname
root@servername DEV #
```

This was discussed in a thread and I confirm it works.
[How to find out version of software package installed on the node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179193/how-to-find-out-version-of-software-package-installed-on-the-node)

I'm looking for the way to simplify this or make more elegant as possible.
Basically, the question is what version will be installed doing yum upgrade/Chef package upgrade?

Comment: Just to be sure, you wish to turn the chef run into an interactive process ?

Comment: The goal would be to save 1.8.0_72 as node attribute. So then I can collect any attribute from multiple hosts using the command in Chef workstation: for HOST in $HOSTS; do knife search node $HOST -l -F json; done

Comment: I got this, it's the final goal I don't understand...

Comment: As I absolutely don't get what you're trying to achieve at end, maybe the documentation for [custom Ohai plugins](https://docs.chef.io/ohai_custom.html) can be of help.(Meant to be updated link to the one mentionned in the linked Q)

Comment: Thanks and sorry if I'm not quite clear. I'm just thinking if Ohai is necessary to get latest java version. Maybe it's possible to get the latest java version somehow from "package 'java' do action: upgrade end", but not doing upgrade? From my understanding, the only one way is Ohai (Chef is not aware about latest java version and doing just yum upgrade java).

Comment: You can just do it in a recipe code, but if the idea is to know the lastest available version in a repo, better use the repo API out of each node chef-run.

Comment: What I mean is that sounds a XY problem, trying to solve how to get this information when the actual problem is elsewhere and is the control over the version installed/available.

Comment: `node.set['whaterver']['attribute'] = shell_out('yum....').stdout` should be enough for what you wish (or not) blog post about it [here](https://www.chef.io/blog/2014/03/12/writing-libraries-in-chef-cookbooks/)

Comment: Tensibai, great one! I totally forgot about shell_out feature. This is really satisfactory and simple solution as I wanted.

Comment: Just add this as answer so then I can mark the thread as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `shell_out` should do for your use case, even if I don't really get the final goal of all of this.

```
node.set['whaterver']['attribute'] = shell_out("yum list all jre1.*[5,6,7,8,9].* | tail -n 1 | cut -f 2").stdout.strip
```

Documentation is [here](https://github.com/chef/mixlib-shellout). The Recipe DSL `shell_out` is a wrapper, it works like `Mixin::ShellOut.new` with some sanity checks.

Comment: You almost certainly want to use `shell_out!` there to raise an exception on error. Also you probably mean to use `shell_out!('…').stdout.strip`. In general I would recommend care before pointing new users at advanced-level patterns when you don't explain them well.

Comment: @coderanger I would say not here, populating an attribute not used should not break the run IMO. Feel free to bake your own answer on this case or to edit with your thoughts but I stand on the no exception call for this one. SO is not chef mailing list, we're not supposed to hold hands here and OP is supposed to do his homework on the answers to learn the pro and cons. Just my opinion of course, you're obviously far better than me on the code.

Comment: Sure, deciding not to throw an exception is fine if you have some other handling for errors. Perhaps set the attribute to nil. But you need to acknowledge errors somehow. Doing "his homework" is impossible because there is no real documentation on this feature of Chef, thus you as the teacher inherit that responsibility.

Comment: @coderanger The readmenof Mixin::ShellOut sounds quite clear. And again, SO is not a teaching platform but a fixing one. There's interesting blog post about shell_out popping up with a search on Google, too much to list in a Q/A on a specific problem. I did answer for the question, I may have forgot something but I think this will return nil if there's an error in yum causing the last command on pipe to return an empty STDOUT. I asked OP to clarify the final intent, out of this I finally gave a 'solution'. You're free to disagree with my behavior as I disagree with yours on SO sometimes ;)