# Setting chef interval and splay time based on the rpm version installed

Tags: chef-infra

Hi I am new to Chef and I am trying out to write a recipe and add in existing cookbook. I want my recipe to find the rpm version of a particular application and based on the results splay and chef interval to be updated. Since I am new I searched in google and found out some results on ohai plugin.

[How to find out version of software package installed on the node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179193/how-to-find-out-version-of-software-package-installed-on-the-node)

When I read on custom ohai plugins, I am not getting clarity whether I can use this to proceed for my work or any other approach to be carried out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming application as Python**

recipes/default.rb

```
version = get_app_version('python') # call to libraries/default.rb

if version > 3.0
    node.override['chef_client']['interval'],node.override['chef_client']['splay'] = <inverval_time>,<splay_time>
elsif version < 3.0
    node.override['chef_client']['interval'],node.override['chef_client']['splay'] = <interval_time>, <splay_time>
end
```

libraries/default.rb

```
def get_app_version(app_name)
    shell_out("#{app_name} --version").stdout
end
```

Hope this should help.